# How could i set a "speed" for the point in pygame/python?

Tags: python, pygame

i am working on a little Game with Pygame and i stumbled across a little thing i couldnt fix by myself. So here is the Problem:

```
    px, py = player_rect.center
    sx, sy = snail_rect.center
    
    
    direction = (px - sx, py - sy)

    dx, dy = (px - sx, py - sy)

    snail_rect.center = (sx + dx / 60, sy + dy / 60)
```

When i now execute it the snail will speed up the farther it is away from the player.
But i now i want that the snail have the same speed no matter how far it is away.
Im pretty new and i hope this snipped is enought so you guys can help me ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to normalize your vector to a unit vector and then properly scale it by a constant speed factor. Try this:

```
import math
dx, dy = (px - sx, py - sy)
length = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
dx /= length
dy /= length

# you can use this already
# or you can do

c = 5
dx = c * dx
dy = c * dy
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason why it's speeding up is because your direction isn't normalized. This is reinforced by your statement of

> the snail will speed up the farther it is away from the player

Normalizing your direction should help resolve this issue for you.